# Differences between version for MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

Where can I find the differences between the IBM MQ versions V8.0.0.5 and V9.0? I tried to look it up on IBM website but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBM's v9 Knowledge center page "[What's new in Version 9.0.0](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q127900_.htm)" lists new things in v9.0.

> [New family features
>   are](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q113120_.htm?view=kc#q113120_):
>
> - Additional quality of protection for IBM MQ AMS
> - Web addressable access to the client channel definition table (CCDT)
> - IBM MQ AMS supported in non-IBM JREs in Java clients
> - Updated Resource Adapter for traditional WebSphere Application Server
> - Enhanced Unicode data conversion support
> - IBM MQ Managed File Transfer Protocol Bridge Agent logging enhancements
>
> [New features for distributed platforms
>   are](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q113130_.htm?view=kc#q113130_):
>
> - Performance monitoring API and enhanced activity trace available through publish/subscribe
> - [Windows] LDAP authorization on Windows platforms
> - [UNIX] runmqsc command line editor for UNIX platforms
>
> [New z/OS® features
>   are](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q113140_.htm?view=kc#q113140_):
>
> - Data manager page set statistics
> - JMS support within CICS OSGI Server
> - JMS support within IMS Server
> - Improved control of messages by using message expiry
> - Increased number of active logs
> - Using IBM z/OSMF to automate IBM MQ

IBM's v9 Knowledge center page "[What's changed in Version 9.0.0](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q001060_.htm)" lists what has changed.

> - [V9.0.0.0][Changes to supported platforms](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q127160_.htm?view=kc)
>     For IBM MQ Version 9.0, some changes are made to the platforms that
>     are supported.
> - [V9.0.0.0][Changes to commands](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q127180_.htm?view=kc)
>     A number of commands have changed at IBM MQ Version 9.0
> - [V9.0.0.0][Command level changes for Version 9.0](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q127150_.htm?view=kc)
>     The command level changes to 900 at IBM MQ Version 9.0
> - [V9.0.0.0][Deprecated, stabilized and removed features](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q127140_.htm?view=kc)
>     A number of features are deprecated, stabilized or removed from IBM MQ
>     Version 9.0.
> - [z/OS][V9.0.0.0][z/OS: Prerequisites for Version 9.0](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q127230_.htm?view=kc)
>     Some prerequisites have changed for Version 9.0.
> - [z/OS][V9.0.0.0][z/OS: Changes to OPMODE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q127165_.htm?view=kc)
>     In previous versions of IBM MQ, if a queue manager was started with
>     OPMODE=(COMPAT,vrm), new functions added at command level vrm would
>     always be available. In IBM MQ Version 9.0 this is no longer the case.

Comment: Thank you Josh, this was very helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at "What's new" document which comes with every MQ release. Search for "IBM MQ Knowledge Center," and navigate to "What's new." Version 9.0 is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q113110_.htm).

Comment: Thank you Yuri :)